# Jasmine test cannot find imported variable

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Angular, I have the following class set up:

```
import { USERS } from "./data/users"; // imports an Array of Objects

export class User {
    constructor(name: string) {
        const user = USERS.find(e => e.name === name);
    }
...
}
```

This is working fine when I compile and build. The website runs as intended. But when I try to unit test it with Jasmine, the test cannot find the const `USERS` and throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`. My spec file is like this:

```
import { User } from './users.module';
import { USERS } from "./data/users";

describe('UserModule', () => {
  let userModule: UserModule;

  beforeEach(() => {
    userModule = new UserModule();
  });

  it('should create a user', () => {
    const user = new User("Testuser");
    expect(user).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Why can't the class User find the variable USERS in testing just like it can in production? What can I make for the class to find that variable?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm hitting this issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

The spec file you posted looks a bit off. You're importing the class `User` but it's not being used; instead you're creating an instance of `UserModule`. That could have something to do with it.